# How do I restart dnsmasq?

Tags: services, dnsmasq

I can't figure out how to restart dnsmasq.

```
service dnsmasq restart
dnsmasq: unrecognized service
```

**SOLUTION**

Restart the network manager (his parent)

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: The solution should be posted as an answer instead of being on the question's body....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the normal Ubuntu destktop configuration, `dnsmasq` is invoked via the NetworkManager, and can be restarted by restarting the `network-manager` service instead i.e.

```
$ pstree -sp $(pidof dnsmasq)
init(1)───NetworkManager(7731)───dnsmasq(7743)
$ 
$ sudo service network-manager restart
network-manager stop/waiting
network-manager start/running, process 7940
$ 
$ pstree -sp $(pidof dnsmasq)
init(1)───NetworkManager(7940)───dnsmasq(7953)
```

Comment: Outdated answer... dnsmasq is ran by systemd on 16.04.

Comment: Hence, it should now be: `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`.

Comment: `service network-manager restart` still work though.. Because `service` can handle some of systemd commands.

Comment: I'm on 18.0.4 using pi-hole and I get service not found

Comment: @Shayan it's `systemd-networkd.service` on ubuntu 18

Answer (score 21):

Just run this command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart
```

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Works on Debian 11 and when one does not use NetworkManager

Comment: Works on Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Answer (score 3):

Simply restarting network manager does not work for me (as in new DNS setup is not used).

```
$ ps aux | grep dns
libvirt+  2217  0.0  0.0  28200   668 ?        S    May30   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --conf-file=/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf
nobody   17685  0.1  0.0  32604  1560 ?        S    14:39   0:01 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --conf-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.conf --cache-size=0 --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

Then so in here you need to run :
`sudo kill 17685`

Then finally
`sudo service network-manager restart`

This applies new the dnsmasq settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have two instances of `dnsmasq` running on my Ubuntu 12.04. The following seems to work to restart both of them:

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
$ sudo stop lxc-net; sudo start lxc-net
```

Example result:

```
$ for p in $(pgrep dnsmasq); do pstree -spu $p; done
init(1)───NetworkManager(19343)───dnsmasq(19417,nobody)
init(1)───dnsmasq(19623,lxc-dnsmasq)

$ sudo service network-manager restart
network-manager stop/waiting
network-manager start/running, process 20048

$ for p in $(pgrep dnsmasq); do pstree -spu $p; done
init(1)───dnsmasq(19623,lxc-dnsmasq)
init(1)───NetworkManager(20048)───dnsmasq(20066,nobody)

$ sudo stop lxc-net; sudo start lxc-net
lxc-net stop/waiting
lxc-net start/running

$ for p in $(pgrep dnsmasq); do pstree -spu $p; done
init(1)───NetworkManager(20048)───dnsmasq(20066,nobody)
init(1)───dnsmasq(20262,lxc-dnsmasq)
```

The `lxc-net` restart is discussed here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxc/+bug/1043588